# Как занести данные из формы Django в бд по внешнему ключу

Tags: python, mysql, django

Есть форма на сайте, где пользователь может выбрать организацию. У меня есть модель Person, с внешним ключом на модель Organization, но я не понимаю, как получить данные из формы так, чтобы привязать Пользователя к выбранной организации.

Модель:

```py
    #models.py
    class Organization(models.Model):
        org_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        def __str__(self):
        return 'Организация: {}'.format(self.org_name)

    class Person(models.Model):
        company = models.ForeignKey(Organization, verbose_name='Компания', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Форма:

```py
    class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
        org = Organization.objects.all()
        OPTIONS = ()
        count = 0
        for i in org:
            count += 1
            OPTIONS += (count, i),
        Company = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple(), choices=OPTIONS)
```

Views:

```py
    def adduser(request):
        data = {}
        if request.method == "POST":
            dbuser = Person()
            form = UserForm(request.POST)
            dbuser.first_name = request.POST.get("FirstName")
            org_name = request.POST.get("Company")
            dborg = Organization().objects.get(name=org_name)
            dborg.person_set.create(name=dbuser.first_name)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                data['form'] = form
                data['res'] = 'Пользователь успешно создан'
            dbuser.save()
            return render(request, 'adduser.html', data)
        else:
            form = UserForm() 
            data['form'] = form
            return render(request, "adduser.html", data)
```

Comment: рекомендую сначала изучить django по официальному туториалу, чтобы понять как работать с формами.  а вообще `dbuser.company = dborg` и `dbuser.save()`

Comment: или `dborg.person_set.add(dbuser)`

Comment: а в идеале вам не нужно получать данные из формы и не надо писать как связывать объекты во вьюхе, пропишите это в `save()` формы